# "sikuli java stderr" files saved in test - Robot Framework with Sikuli

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, sikuli

how are you?

I'm have a question. Could you help me?

I'm using **Robot Framework** (version 5.0, Python version 3.9.11) with **Sikuli** (version 2.0.5).

**Operating System**: Windows 10 Pro.

I'm sending the following command in PowerShell (I've already tried it in cmd too), this one inside my repository:

```
set DISABLE_SIKULI_LOG=1
```

The purpose of the above command is to make the files (sikuli_java_stderr and sikuli_java_stdout) not saved.

After using the above command and running the tests using the command `robot .\spb\tests\test.robot` in Power Shell or cmd, the files are still saved (sikuli_java_stderr)

What am I doing wrong?

Print from the files below:

[image]

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Before running the tests you have to define the environment variable `DISABLE_SIKULI_LOG=1`.

For example in Linux I have it in `~/.bashrc`, like:

```
export DISABLE_SIKULI_LOG=1
```

On Windows it can be:

```
set DISABLE_SIKULI_LOG=1
```

Comment: Helio, thank you! Is it a file I should open? If so, where is this file?
Or is it just playing this command?

Comment: It is an environment variable, you can set it in the command/terminal/shell where you are running the test.

Comment: It didn't work... =/ I sent it in the root of the project. I ran the test and generated these files again...
What can it be?

Comment: Please edit your question, so it shows how you run the robot test.

Comment: I run the test by the command itself "robot ."
Did you understand?

Comment: I do understand, that you did not understand. Just enter the command I wrote `set` before running the robot command. To make it permanent add that variable definition to you operating system environment variables.

Comment: Helio, I did what you suggested, but the files are still being saved. =/. What can it be? Thanks.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Please edit your question by adding the commands you use in a command window/terminal/shell (if you told us what operating system you use, it would be easier).

Comment: Helio, I edited the question in the text, describing in more detail the commands used and the Operating System.
Could you check and help me if possible? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `cmd` instead of `powershell`. And in `powershell` you may need to use a different command (that is why I don't use powershell), like Set-Property $env.DISABLE_SIKULI_LOG=1  (I really don't know if this is the command).

Comment: Helio, I used the command with cmd. Unsuccessfully.
Files continue to be saved. =//

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me on Windows 10 and PowerShell is the command setx instead of set.

```
setx DISABLE_SIKULI_LOG 1
```

[More info here](https://superuser.com/a/916652)